# Application viewer setfullscreen function not hiding ubuntu sidebar

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml, fullscreen, ubuntu-unity

I'm building the UI for an application using Qt and QML for Ubuntu Linux. I have a viewer window with a canvas element which is supposed to be fullscreen by default. On opening the application this works fine (i.e. Ubuntu sidebar and top taskbar are hidden). However, once I minimize my application and then maximize it again by using `viewer->setFullScreen();`, the Ubuntu sidebar and top taskbar are still visible and there is an offset while writing on the canvas due to the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this topic on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181071/launchbar-panel-overlaps-when-showing-a-dialog-box-in-fullscreen), your problem do really looks like Unity bug (or feature). But, according to somehow related bug on [Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181071/launchbar-panel-overlaps-when-showing-a-dialog-box-in-fullscreen), it seems that you can get desired behavior by:

> Turn "Always On Top" on via right-clicking the titlebar of your window, before making it go fullscreen.
>   This will prevent the Unity panel from rendering on top of this fullscreen-window, when using the other screen.

In Qt you can set `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` to your window/widget via [`QWidget::windowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop).

Pay additional attention to notes in official documentation:

- This function calls `setParent()` when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call `show()` to make the widget visible again.
- About `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` -- Informs the window system that the window should stay on top of all other windows. Note that on some window managers on X11 you also have to pass `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint` for this flag to work correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this. Now the position of the window is as I expect it to be but the window is frozen (I'm not able to write anything on the canvas.)